# Azure Media services, create locator fails using .NET library

Tags: .net, azure-media-services

An old V2 Media services account used to be working happily with the given code:

```
var contentKeys = new List<StreamingLocatorContentKey>
{
    new StreamingLocatorContentKey(
        contentKeyId,
        StreamingLocatorContentKeyType.CommonEncryptionCenc,
        "cencKeyDefault",
        Convert.ToBase64String(contentKeyValue))
};

return await mClient.StreamingLocators.CreateAsync(
    mResourceGroupName, mAccountName,
    locatorName,
    new StreamingLocator(assetName, PredefinedStreamingPolicy.MultiDrmCencStreaming,
                         defaultContentKeyPolicyName: "KeyPolicy",
                         contentKeys: contentKeys));
```

Here `locatorName` is `$"Locator-{contentKeyId:N}"`. This code created a locator with the predefined key. Now the call throws a `BadRequest` exception with no additional details.

1. Creating a new account, V2 or V3, yields the same result.
2. Removing `contentKeys: contentKeys` makes the code work again - but I need to pass on the key value, so no good for me. Still, this indicates that there is something wrong with the key part of the request.
3. Using the following `POST` request works fine:

   ```
    POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroup}}/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/{{msName}}/streamingLocators/Locator-A1?api-version=2021-11-01

    {
        "properties": {
            "assetName": "Video-A1",
            "streamingPolicyName": "Predefined_MultiDrmCencStreaming",
            "defaultContentKeyPolicyName": "KeyPolicy",
            "contentKeys": [
            {
                "labelReferenceInStreamingPolicy": "cencKeyDefault",
                "id": "60000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                "value": "1UqLohAfWsEGkULYxHjYZg=="
            }]
        }
    }
   ```

So it's not *Azure* per se, it must be the way the request is generated, or the way I use the API.

#### Environment

- Project: *.NET 6*
- Microsoft.Azure.Common: 2.2.1
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media: 6.0.0
- Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob: 11.2.3
- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication: 2.4.1

So, what could have become wrong in my code? And how can I debug the Azure calls to get the error message, not just the `BadRequest` code?

#### PS

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/streaming-locators/create?tabs=HTTP#streaminglocatorcontentkey) erroneously mentions `cencDefaultKey`, that does not work - it must be `cencKeyDefault`.

#### PPS

Apparently, when trying to insert a table, StackOverflow believes it is a badly formatted code - on submittin, preview works fine. Took me a few attempts to identify the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easiest to debug the issue if you file a support ticket from Azure Portal with your media account information and request information.

Since you mention that getting rid of the `contentkeys` parameter fixes the `BadRequest`, it is possible that there is a mismatch between the number of content keys specified in the Streaming Policy and the number of keys that you are specifying when creating the locator. If you do not specify any key, the server auto-generates all the required keys.

Additionally, `BadRequest` responses should always contain useful information. You can capture that by either routing your requests through an app like `Fiddler` or using a code snippet like below:

```
try
{
    await Client.StreamingLocators.CreateAsync(ResourceGroup, MediaAccount, locator.Name, locator);
}
catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Response.Content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to retrieve the message, which said:

"Content key id '0495fa02-006b-4276-a2ef-26b405efe013' already exists, please choose another one"

I guess, that means I cannot duplicate keys from one account to another one - despite those are two different accounts.